# Converting Old PGP Keys to GPG - [RESOLVED]

Tags: linux, gpg, pgp

We were migrating from Solaris to Linux where we used PGP v6.5.2 in Solaris. We need to use GPG in Linux now. I installed GPG 2.0.14 having libgcrypt v1.4.5. While trying to decrypt files generated with the PGP key, it wasn't happening because there is no support on the IDEA algorithm. so, I've installed GPG 2.2.1 with libgcrypt 1.8.1, where there is support for IDEA. Now, in order to test the same, I needed the keys. I could import the keys using the GPG 2.0.14 (this is before installing gpg 2.2.1 in a custom directory; not /usr/bin).

While trying to import the old pgp key, the gpg 2.2.1 says : skipped PGP-2 keys.

```
$ gpg --import /app/lcdb/mansh_pub.asc 
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:     skipped PGP-2 keys: 1
```

I found some clues that the key in in old format for the gpg 2.2.1 to import - that's the new feature.

Now, my problem is : How do I import old pgp key with gpg2.2.1?

Below is what I tried:

```
$ gpg --list-packets mansh_pub.asc
# off=0 ctb=99 tag=6 hlen=3 plen=269
:key packet: [obsolete version 3]
# off=272 ctb=b4 tag=13 hlen=2 plen=51
:user ID packet: "Manish Shrimali"
$ /usr/bin/gpg --list-packets mansh_pub.asc
:public key packet:
        version 3, algo 1, created 1158180784, expires 0
        pkey[0]: [2048 bits]
        pkey[1]: [5 bits]
        keyid: C6FDEE2916F3C241
:user ID packet: "Manish Shrimali"
$ gpg --edit-key C6FDEE2916F3C241
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.1; Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

gpg: key "C6FDEE2916F3C241" not found: No public key
$ /usr/bin/gpg --edit-key C6FDEE2916F3C241
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.14; Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Secret key is available.

pub  2048R/16F3C241  created: 2006-09-13  expires: never       usage: SCEA
                     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
[ unknown] (1). Manish Shrimali 
Command> passwd
Key is protected.
gpg: protection algorithm 1 (IDEA) is not supported
Can't edit this key: Invalid cipher algorithm

Command> quit
```

Can you please suggest how to come out this loop and resolve the issue?

Regards, Sirisha.

Comment: Did you try `expert` mode? Some of the newer or more advanced features are only available when specifying `expert`... like this `gpg --expert --edit-key C6FDEE2916F3C241`

Comment: I tried. but problem is, I cannot be able to import the key with gpg 2.2.1 as it says "skipped PGP-2 keys: 1" In order to import, I need to edit the key. For editing, I first have to have the key. it's a loop. The key is imported with gpg 2.0.14, and can be edited. but It's not allowing to edit the key with gpg2.0.14 because there's no support on IDEA cipher.

Comment: I paged through the PGP6 documentation a little.  It's unclear if you can export the secret keys without a passphrase.  If you can export the secret keys without a passphrase from PGP6, perhaps you will be able to import them into GPG... I also looked through the GPG source a little.  There are instructions to limit GPG to use PGP6 compatibility mode using the `--pgp6` option, but that seems like it just limits the visible algos.  There are compile options to disable IDEA altogether.  Make sure IDEA is present in the list with `gpg --version` ... exporting w/o passphr is not good, but may work

Comment: I really want to show you the following URLs. It's worth reading. I hope they can help you.  https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/pgp2x.html and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=190509. Read the 2nd first.

Comment: Finally, it worked with gpg 1.4.19v which has IDEA support and is also able to use the keys imported. It throws a warning, but then, it decrypts the file. No need to edit-keys. Thanks!

Comment: @RubberStamp: I have compiled the libgcrypt1.8.1 to support IDEA algorithm. The problem was with the GPG version 2.2.0, where they removed the support for importing old keys that has incompatible format.

Comment: I think @Bruce is pointing out that the secret keys exported out of PGP6 need to be in binary format and not ascii armored and the keys need to be self-signed.  Can you confirm that the exported secret keys are binary and not ascii armored... and are also self-signed?

Comment: Okay. The keys are ascii armored and are also self-signed.